# resetting a timer when a var is empty

Tags: c#, timer

I'm using C# to create an app that plays certain Youtube videos when they are requested and placed in a database via a website I have created too. Then the program I am building will take the request and will open it in Chrome and play it. After the video is done, it will terminate the webbrowser.exe process. When its terminated the record will be deleted from the database so the song won't get played again. And the timer i have made will begin again and will wait 5 minutes to play the next song. This works fine, but the problem is that when there is no record in the database the program crashes, how can i get it to restart the timer again?
This is a snippet of my code where the problem is;

```
    Execute();
    InitializeComponent();
    var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => Execute());
    aTimer.Interval = 300000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
public void Execute()
{
    int Tijd;
    int Videolengte;
    string resultaat;
    string URL = "";

    Database db = new Database(CONNECTION_STRING);
    object[] result = db.GetFirstRecord();


        URL = (string)result[1];
        Process browser = Process.Start(@"chrome.exe",
              "http:\\www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + URL);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 15);
```

section, i need to make an if statement that check if var result is empty, but what can i make it to start at the aTimer again? (Sorry for the bad formatting, i am not experienced with this.

Comment: Please remove all irrelevant code, this is kind of a mess. Formatting will be done for you by moderators if not correct.

Comment: Done, looks better now indeed

Comment: Just check if the database is empty in `Execute()` and return if so. The timer will tick again at the next interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could check all the array, for sample:

```
// check if there is something in the collection
if (result != null && result.Any() && result.Count >= 1)
{
    URL = result[1] as string;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(URL))
    {
       // continue safe ...
    }    
    else
    {
        // stop the timer... or something like this
        aTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Just to ensure, [`aTimer.Enabled=true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the same for [`aTimer.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) such as [`aTimer.Enable=false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  is the same for [`aTimer.Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer.stop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)